# Ternary Operator: "Parsing error: Property assignment expected"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-operator

This is my code basically:

```
const [jwtToken, setJwtToken] = useState("")
return(
    {(jwtToken === "") ? <div>Yes</div> : <div>No</div>}
)
```

Why do I get this error?:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember it worked like this for me (added some parentheses and empty html tag):

```
return(
  <>{(jwtToken === "") ? (<div>Yes</div>) : (<div>No</div>)}</>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [jwtToken, setJwtToken] = useState("")
  return (
    (jwtToken === "") ? <div>Yes</div> : <div>No</div>
  )
```

In this case you don't need to use {}

You can also use React.Fragment